# Get all the dates from a given week number and year

Tags: javascript, date, week-number

Suppose I have a week number 43 and a year 2020

How do I get so that the output would be

```
dates = ['Monday, October 19, 2020', 
        'Tuesday, October 20, 2020',
        'Wednesday, October 21, 2020',
        'Thursday, October 22, 2020',
        'Friday, October 23, 2020',
        'Saturday, October 24, 2020',
        'Sunday, October 24, 2020',]
```

I've tried this one but it gives me Sunday to Saturday which results to incorrect date range for week 43:

```js
function getDateOfWeek(w, y) {
  var simple = new Date(y, 0, 1 + (w - 1) * 7);
  var dow = simple.getDay();
  var ISOweekStart = simple;
  if (dow <= 4)
    ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() - simple.getDay() + 1);
  else
    ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() + 8 - simple.getDay());
  const temp = {
    d: ISOweekStart.getDate(),
    m: ISOweekStart.getMonth(),
    y: ISOweekStart.getFullYear(),
  }
  const numDaysInMonth = new Date(temp.y, temp.m + 1, 0).getDate()

  return Array.from({
    length: 7
  }, _ => {
    if (temp.d > numDaysInMonth) {
      temp.m += 1;
      temp.d = 1;
    }
    return new Date(temp.y, temp.m, temp.d++).toUTCString()
  });
}

console.log(getDateOfWeek(43, 2020));
```

Comment: You open to using a library like momentJS? It seriously simplifies the act of working with dates in JS. You should also be aware that the first day of the week varies by locale. So you might think of Monday as the first day of the week, some locales call this SUnday and that might affect your result here.

Comment: It's a timezone issue: you're using local dates up until `... toUTCString()`, which uses UTC. Either use all UTC or all local values (e.g. use *toDateString* instead).

Comment: @Jamiec—the first day of the week varies greatly and is pretty much a personal choice, I don't think it's reliably consistent at a locale level (especially where "locale" is defined by language code). The identifier *ISOweekStart* indicates the OP is using ISO week number, so Monday is day 1.

Comment: @RobG You're right that an ISO Week starts on a Monday - but I assure you this can be Sunday or even Saturday based on locale.

Comment: @Jamiec—sure, I lived for some years in an Islamic country where the week started on Saturday. Among people I know living locally, opinion is divided on whether the week starts on Sunday or Monday. Even government administrations can't agree.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @Jamiec. All of the hassle by using native javascript date can be simplified by using momentjs

```
getDateOfWeek(d) {
            var startOfPeriod = this.moment(d),
            begin = this.moment(startOfPeriod).isoWeekday(1);

            begin.startOf('isoWeek');

            let str = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                str += begin.format('ddd MMMM DD YYYY') + ',';
                begin.add('d', 1)
            }

            return str.split(',');
        },
```

above code will return the array of dates starting from monday to sunday